# Why doesn't vim recognize a new file type?

Tags: vim, file-type

I am trying to get vim to recognize a filetype.vim file consisting of the following:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif

augroup autodetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.ish  setfiletype perl
augroup END
```

This file is in the directory ~/programs/vim

My .vimrc file contains the following line:

```
set runtimepath=~/programs/vim,$VIMRUNTIME
```

I checked that this line is being executed by typing ":set runtimepath?" The result is "runtimepath=~/programs/vim,/usr/share/vim/vim74".

But when I open a file such as ish.ish, the vim filetype variable is set to 'on'. When I open x.pl, the vim filetype variable is set to 'perl'.

I can fix the problem by copying (or moving) filetype.vim to the ~/.vim directory (without changing runtimepath). Why doesn't vim recognize filetype.vim in ~/programs/vim?

Answer (score 4):

The `'runtimepath'` option is meant to tell Vim where to look for "standard" `*.vim` files such as colorschemes and plugins. Try `:echo &rtp` in a clean Vim session to see what it should look like and read `:help 'runtimepath'`. By setting this option to a meaningless value you effectively make Vim unable to find those files and thus work correctly.

To add a specific directory to `'runtimepath'`, use the following syntax:

```
set runtimepath+=/path/to/directory
```

But what's the reason you'd want to use a non-standard directory for standard scripts? What's wrong with `~/.vim`?

The *most obvious* way to tell Vim about a new filetype is to add these lines to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup autodetect
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.ish set filetype=perl
augroup END
```

The *cleanest* way is to put this line in `~/.vim/ftdetect/ish.vim`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.ish set filetype=perl
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Before making any changes to my .vimrc file, the value of runtimepath was '/home/levner/programs/vim,/usr/share/vim/vim74'. After I replaced the line in .vimrc that set runtimepath to your suggestion, 'set runtimepath+=/path/to/directory', runtimepath was '/home/levner/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/home/levner/.vim/after,/home/levner/programs/vim'. I didn't notice any change in behavior: color highlighting worked for standard files (like .pl) and didn't work for .ish files.

Comment: As to why I want to put vim scripts in a non-standard directory, I keep all my programs in a 'programs' directory under my home directory. There is a 'perl' subdirectory under 'programs', a 'javascript' subdirectory, a 'sh' subdirectory, a 'vim' subdirectory, and so on. Copying all my programs for use on another computer, or making a backup, is easy--I just back up ~/programs.

Comment: I know about creating a ~/.vim/ftdetect/ish.vim file. It works. However, creating ~/programs/vim/ftdetect/ish.vim does not work. I may be forced to use ~/.vim (I can create a symbolic link from ~/programs/vim to ~/.vim), but I consider this to be a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Well, your entire issue is caused by your decision to use a non-standard location for those file. Enjoy the dirty workaround for a bad idea. Add an autocommand to your `~/.vimrc` and call it a day.

Comment: romainl, I assure you that being uncivil will have no effect on me; I will continue being civil.

Comment: I have found that my filetype.vim file is detected properly by vim 7.4.205. On the Fedora 20 system where the problem occurs, vim 7.4.179 is running. I filed a low priority bug report, (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1118044), for this issue hoping that the Fedora team will make a more current version of vim available. I could probably build a more recent version myself, but it's a lot easier to type 'yum update vim'.